# Many processes such as git and node are running 10x too slow on Windows 10, but run fast in safe mode

Tags: windows-10, performance, powershell, git, node.js

Several command-line programs seem a little slow on a PC. How can I troubleshoot?  For example, on this PC, It takes over a half-second to run `git status`:

```
PS> for (;;) { Measure-Command { git status } | findstr TotalSeconds  }
TotalSeconds      : 0.7119173
TotalSeconds      : 0.6040415
TotalSeconds      : 0.6117674
TotalSeconds      : 0.5779911
TotalSeconds      : 0.6069439
...
```

(On another PC, the above runs in 0.05 s.) A few other commands I've noticed take just a bit too long as well:

```
PS>  for (;;) { Measure-Command { node --version } | findstr TotalSeconds  }
TotalSeconds      : 0.4630501
TotalSeconds      : 0.3144418
TotalSeconds      : 0.2842615
TotalSeconds      : 0.2808537
```

(The other PC runs that in 0.02 s.)

One more for good measure:

```
PS> for (;;) { Measure-Command { npm --version } | findstr TotalSeconds  }
TotalSeconds      : 3.4839123
TotalSeconds      : 3.1501913
TotalSeconds      : 2.9817682
TotalSeconds      : 3.0423125
```

When these programs are running, I see CPU usage jump up, as if it is pegging 1/4th of the CPU's four cores.  The CPU usage is elevated only in the process I invoked itself (i.e. Git.exe or Node.exe), not in any other process.

[image]

I have tried disabling as many Windows services as I can, to the point where my PC can barely do anything, yet I still get timings similar to the above.  I have ensured that antivirus, firewall, and BeyondTrust are disabled, and the problem persists.  I do not have ATI graphics (Intel HD 520 only).

The timings are the same whether I invoke from Powershell, cmd.exe, or bash.

**The problem goes away in safe mode.**

After booting normally, I've tried stopping all non-essential processes; the slowness persists.  I've tried disabling all non-essential Windows services; the slowness persists.  I've tried disabling all non-essential hardware in the Device Manager; the slowness persists.

Can anyone suggest a next troubleshooting step?  I fear the cause of these issues is also slowing down other apps, as well.

Comment: How about rebooting every once in a while? You have an insane amount of handles open. There’s probably something leaking handles.

Comment: Are both PCs with Windows 10? I experienced the same with cli tools on Windows in contrast to Linux. I found out that using these tools in a VirtualBox with Linux on a Windows system was faster then using these tools directly on Windows

Comment: @ThomasSablik Both PCs have Windows 10.

Comment: @DanielB I rebooted and ran the above again, and got very similar timings. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: So you are saying the factor is about 10. Is it possible, that the other PC is accordingly more performant? SSD vs. HDD, notebook vs. desktop. Something like that.

Comment: The systems are similar enough.  They both have SSDs, Quad Core i7s, and are both notebooks.  I thought, on a command like `git status`, it wouldn't matter too much?

Comment: Same thing when running in Safe Mode? Have you tried using sysinternal's Process Monitor?

Comment: I would first run Process Monitor, and consider the modules be loaded (Load Image) by the processes, anything being loaded that isn't required?  If so, prevent these modules from loading.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "modules" or "load image".  I see the process tree in SysInternals Process Explorer (not "Monitor"), and it gives me no clues of CPU use except by the process I am running--in the examples above, git.exe and node.exe.

Comment: @root, things are MUCH MUCH faster in safe mode, which is a good clue.  But, having already tried shutting down as many processes and Windows services as I can.  Any next step suggestions?

Comment: I've edited the question to elaborate on what else I've found.

Comment: You've disabled services, but have you also disabled startup applications?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, it was indeed Symantec Endpoint Protection.  Disabling the services doesn't seem to prevent the problem, but the following does.  Run this to confirm it ends the problem.

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\smc.exe" -stop
```

This, however, leaves me without Symantec Endpoint Protection.

There may be a way to whitelist certain programs with Symantec, but I'm not sure what it is.

EDIT: We subsequently found that the real delay came from Application and Device Control, not the bulk of SEP.  This can be disabled in Settings > Client Management > General, at the bottom.

(Even deeper, there seems to be an experimental feature in only part of Application and Device Control that causes a delay on every process start.  I am not sure what it is.)

Comment: I've had this problem for months and couldn't find the issue. Now it's solved. Not the only issue Symantec causes... Many thanks!